# ELMAH does not work after moving to a new server

Tags: elmah

I made a complete copy of the old web application.
Copied it to the new server.
Made appropriate SQL Server changes and it does not work.

ELMAH Version: v1.0.3705
OS: Windows Server 2012
IIS 8

Comment: Can we see some code/config please?

Comment: <sectionGroup name="elmah">
   <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah"/>
   <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah"/>
   <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah"/>
   <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah"/>
  </sectionGroup>

Comment: <httpModules>
      <add name="OnlineActiveUsers" type="OnlineActiveUsers.OnlineUsersModule"/>
   <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
   <!--ELMAH #########################-->
   <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
   <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah"/>
   <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah"/>
  </httpModules>
  <!--Options for f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I found your answer.  You need to grant your IIS AppPool permission to modify (or write) to the path you have instructed ELMAH to write the XML.  To do this, bring up Windows File Explorer, locate the path and folder where ELMAH is writing those XML, right click to get folder menu and select properties, locate and click on the tab labeled SECURITY, and follow the instructions described in this URL:
http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities